# how to create sub menu in left side bar

Tags: html, css

i am new to HTML and i need to put some sub menus in my side bar.. just like a dropdown but it opens on the right side. and how can i put links on it. thanks

html

```
<ul>
    <li></br>
        <a class="active"  href="?">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li></br>
        <a href="?">Manage Users</a> ----> needs the dropdown here
    </li>        
    <li></br>
        <a href="?">Manage Employees</a>----> needs the dropdown here
    </li>
    <li></br>
        <a href="?">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li></br>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/logout') ?>">Log-Out</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is my css.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

...................................................................

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li></br>
    <a class="active"  href="?">HOME</a>
</li>
<li></br>
    <a href="?">Manage Users</a> ----> needs the dropdown here
</li>        
<li></br>
    <a href="?">Manage Employees</a>---->
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> You put the sublists here</a></li> 
        <li> Many has you need</li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li></br>
    <a href="?">Search</a>
</li>
<li></br>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/logout') ?>">Log-Out</a>
</li>
```

Comment: what happens is that it becomes 
Manage Employees
You put the sublists here
You put the sublists here
You put the sublists here
rather than

Manage Users

Manage Employees

Search

Log-Out with on click sub menus

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the </br> (correct would be <br/>, or <br>for HTML5). I tried to make a simple solution with jQuery. where you simply display or not the content you want.

Hope it is what you were looking for.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*width: 15%;*/
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="active" href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="$('ul#contentUsers').toggle();">Manage Users</a>
        <ul id="contentUsers" style="display: none;">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="$('ul#contentEmployees').toggle();">Manage Employees</a>
        <ul id="contentEmployees" style="display: none;">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Log-Out</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can it be that for exmple when i click Manage Users, Manage Employees

Search

Log-Out, wont disappear?

Comment: I commented out the width and position styles in your CSS, so if you click on Manage Users it will "add" the submenu to your list.
What do you really want to achieve, or which behaviour you want for the list?